# Are there standard tolerances for dimensional lumber?

Tags: wood, lumber, error-tolerance

I understand that the actual dimensions of dimensional lumber are slightly smaller than their nominal dimensions, like how a 2x4 is actually 1½" x 3½". Are there industry standard tolerances on how close a board needs to be to those sizes? When I search for this, I get results about tolerances for framing and assembly, not the boards themselves. For example, I'm looking for something like "the 1½" dimension on lumber must be within 1.50±0.05" over the entire board's length, and the 3½" dimension must be 3.50±0.08" over the entire board's length."

Are there similar tolerances for the form of the lumber? For example, "For boards 6' or shorter, they may not be bowed more than 1/4" and no more than 0.10" per foot, may not be crooked more than 1/4" and no more than 0.10" per foot, may not be cupped more than 0.10" at any cross section, and may not be twisted by more than 5 degrees and no more than 2 degrees per foot, and each end of the board must be perpendicular within 0.10".

The dimensions and form of the board may change over time due to environmental conditions, but there must be some standards for when they are initially cut, right?

Comment: Yes there are. Raw cut wood is actually 2x4.

Comment: For what purpose do you need this information?

Comment: It's possible those standards exist, but all that falls apart in the real world. Wood dries out and defects appear. Sometimes you send it back; sometimes you buy new; other times you make it work.

Comment: '"For boards 6' or shorter, they may not be bowed more than 1/4" and no more than 0.10" per foot' That would be my dream lumber! I've seen stuff at the local big box store that would be perfect for the bows of a boat without any additional bending!

Comment: @RMDman I'm a hobbyist who recently searched through some boards at a hardware store to find one even close to straight, so it made me curious. I measured a 1x6x4 (edit: after I had bought it and taken it home) and found it to be bowed by 5/16", crooked by just over 1/16", visibly twisted a few degrees, and with a width varying from 5.42" to 5.53" over its length. This was one of the best boards that the store had!  That was more variation that I was expecting. I looked for standard tolerances and didn't find anything, so I decided to ask here.

Comment: @Apoapsis,  Ok you're a hobbyist.  You obviously haven't shopped for wood and experienced what is available.  Also the reason there are table saws, routers, planers and a plethora of other wood shaping and servicing tools.

Comment: Try shopping at a lumberyard, letting them know what you're looking for. Woodworking supply stores also often have some selection of higher-grade lumber that may be milled to a finished or near-finished size. I seem to remember there's a woodworking stack; you would probably find more detailed advice there.

Answer (score 3):

There absolutely are standards. For dimensional lumber, the document you're looking for is the "National Grading Rule for Dimension Lumber." Here is [a link to the 2012 version in PDF](http://secure.itswebs.com/nawla/Level_II_Jeopardy/story_content/external_files/National_Grading_Rules.pdf). This is way out of my wheelhouse though, so I won't try to turn the rules for skip, crook, cup, wane, and warp in to numbers for you. Good luck with it. It's a fun looking standard.

In the end, though, your local store probably has what they have. Get used to using your planer. Also: my experience has been that dedicated lumber yards tend to get better stuff than the big box stores.